# Create help page for DataContracts made with the System.Xml.Serialization class

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization, datacontract

I have a WCF Webservice which provides endpoints created with the **System.Xml.Serialization** class and the **System.Runtime.Serialization** class. Now I tried to create the HTTP Help Page. But I have one problem the Response Schema and Response Example was not create automatically for the **DataContracts**, which were created with the **System.Xml.Serialization** class. On the other hand the **Response Schema** and **Response Example** were created succesfully for the DataContracts, which were made with the **System.Runtime.Serialization** class.

I used the **System.Xml.Serialization** class because I needed some Attributes in the XML file.

I get for the **Response Schema** created with the **System.Xml.Serialization** class the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Schemas/>
```

and for the **Response Example**:

```
Could not generate example for response. Failed with error: The object reference was not set to an object instance.
```